# AFNetworking 1.x to 3.x migration - get download progress?

Tags: objective-c, ios9, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, afnetworking-3

I need to download image with progress bar. This is what I've got for in AFNetworking 1.x which is not working for AFNetworking 3.x.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.mediaItem.media_item_hd_url]];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
op.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];

[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    UIImage *image = responseObject;
    _image = image;

    [self.delegate browserItem:self loaded:1.0 finished:YES];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) { }];

[op setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    CGFloat progress = ((CGFloat)totalBytesRead)/((CGFloat)totalBytesExpectedToRead);
    [self.delegate browserItem:self loaded:progress finished:NO];
}];

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];
```

Finally this is what I could come up with, which is not complete. I have no idea how to use progress in code block.

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.mediaItem.media_item_hd_url]];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];

    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
//        UIImage *image = response;
//        _image = image;

        [self.delegate browserItem:self loaded:1.0 finished:YES];

    }];

    [downloadTask resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get best framework **RSNetworkKit** which handles all the network call with an ease. It has internally implemented **AFNetworking 3.0.**  It'll gives you download progress in single method either you upload, download.

It has also an enhanced method to show progress on **UIImageView**.
You can find it here. https://github.com/rushisangani/RSNetworkKit